# Python - can't find file used in the imported file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I loaded a file in a.py using panda:

```
candidates = pd.read_csv("../train_v1.csv")
model = ........
```

In b.py, I firstly import the a.py as:

```
import a as trained_model
```

Then, I called the model constructed in a.py. The system can't find the file that I loaded in a.py, and gave:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../train_v1.csv'
```

How should I get this to work?

Comment: It looks like you need to verify the path to the file from where you're trying to access it

Comment: @G.Anderson May I ask what do you mean by verifying? thanks

Comment: The error is telling you that it can't find the file, so I mean you should check the path from the script to the file you're trying to open

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the aboslute path.
Example your project directory is `C:\Test\project\`
your file is in the directory `C\Test\data\` and called `train_v1.csv`

then do not use the **relative path** `../data/train_v1.csv`
use `C:\Test\data\train_v1.csv`